# How to target the header of the mudexpansionpanel with css

Tags: css, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I want the header of the MudExpansionPanel to be a different colour to the body of the content on the panel.

The MudExpansionPanel has the colour pink assigned in the Style attributes.

`<MudExpansionPanel Text="Heading text" Style="@($"background-color:pink; color:black">`

This turns the entire panel (including when it is expanded). I just want the heading to change colour.
How could I implement this?

Edit: Sorry I didn't explain myself too well. I want the colour to be dynamic. So for one panel I want it to be pink and for another blue ect..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

To get the header a colour I wrote:

```
 <MudExpansionPanel Text="Panel Heading" Style="@($"background-color:{@changingVaraible1}; color:{@changingVaraible2};")" IsInitiallyExpanded="false">
```

To get the expanded rest of the panel white:

CSS:

```
.mud-collapse-wrapper-inner { 
    background: white;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, add a custom CSS file to the project and register it in the `index.html` or `_Host.cshtml`

**Pay attention to the priority of CSS files**

Then apply your desired styles as below

```
.mud-expand-panel-header{
    color:pink;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question specifically, you can target the elements inside the MudExpansionPanel element like this:

```
.mud-expand-panel-header *{ /* this target all element inside mud-expand-panel-header*/
  color: black; /*specify the color add !important if needed*/
}
```

Instead of **'*'** above, you can use class or other valid identifier.

```
.mud-expand-panel-header div { /* or . */
  color: black;
  background: white;
}
```